# Swift - Animations forward and backwards between view controllers

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm designing an ios app using Swift 4.0. I currently have two view controllers in which I have an `UIView` image of waves that is 1606 wide and 628 in height:
 [image: Waves Picture]

In the first view controller, the waves sit at the bottom of the screen as such:
 [image: Initial Position]

When I swipe up, I have the following data that gets passed through the segue:

```
let waveHeight = hundred?.layer.presentation()?.position.y // Current height of waves. This is a global variable

let nextViewController = segue.destination as! Secondary // nextViewController is the segue destination

nextViewController.initialXPosition = nextXPosition // this will be the initial state of the waves in the secondary view controller. Also a global variable
```

In order for seamless transition to occur, I need to start the waves in the secondary view controller exactly where it left off in the initial view controller. The product looks like this:

https://giphy.com/gifs/2A4bUGE9UFUrG9RHPG

Moving on, when I swipe up the waves need to travel upwards accordingly (100 units). To accomplish this, I have used the following method:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.hundred.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -100)

        self.waveHeight = self.hundred?.layer.presentation()?.position.y
    }, completion: nil)
```

At this point, the waves are moving across the screen smoothly and they swiped up by 100 units.

Perfect.

Now swiping down is where the problems occur. I just want to use the same method to get back to the initial screen smoothly; store the current wave height, pass it back through a segue to the initial view controller and have the waves translate down by 100 units.

This does not work.

For some reason, I cannot store the y-position of the waves in the second view controller. I have print statements setup and no matter where I am in the animation when I swipe down, the console returns the same value every time. Therefore, when I return to the initial view controller, the waves automatically advance to the bottom of the screen. It is very choppy.

Is there a better way to pass animations back and forth between view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass animation state back and forth between 2 view controllers, perhaps a seperate object, referenced by both view controllers, should be controlling the single animation state.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to pass animations back and forth between view controllers?

**Yes.** Create your own subclass of [`UIStoryboardSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue) and implement the [`perform()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue/1621912-perform) method to run the animation. A segue has access to both the source and destination view controllers, so it's a single object that can both animate the source controller's view off the screen and animate the destination controller's view onto the screen. Doing all the animation in one place means you won't have to "pass animations back and forth" at all.